# Cannot find package

Tags: server, package-management

```
root@ubuntu-server:~# apt-get install lamp-server^
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package lamp-server^
E: Couldn't find task 'lamp-server'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'lamp-server^'
```

Comment: And let  me know if have any issue?

Answer (score 3):

**Answer2:** If you are installing a package for the first time then you have update source cache and you can install.

In terminal do as

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install lamp-server^
```

**Answer1:** You can install it with tasksel easily.

```
sudo apt-get install tasksel ; sudo tasksel
```

and in the options choose LAMP server and forward.

Hope it helps.

Comment: root@ubuntu-server:~# apt-get install gedit
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package gedit

                why??

Comment: @sahrizals first do , sudo apt-get update then try

Comment: when update.. only this appears.

root@ubuntu-server:~# sudo apt-get update
sudo: unable to resolve host ubuntu-server
Ign http://download.owncloud.org  InRelease
Hit http://download.owncloud.org  Release.gpg
Hit http://download.owncloud.org  Release
Hit http://download.owncloud.org  Packages
Ign http://download.owncloud.org  Translation-en_SG
Ign http://download.owncloud.org  Translation-en
Reading package lists... Done

Comment: and unable locate too

Comment: Issue is simple , your server unable to reach to update server all URL's. From update manager settings try to choose best mirror from your location and try installing from that.

Answer (score 1):

Try running the following:

```
sudo tasksel install lamp-server
```

**Reference:**

- [Lamp applications](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/lamp-overview.html)

Comment: root@ubuntu-server:~# apt-get install gedit
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package gedit

how about this one?